# Pesquisar usuários cadastrados e mostrar mesma página

Tags: php

Estou com os seguintes erros
Minha cabeça está fritando demais e não consigo ver o erro

**Notice: Undefined index: cxnome**

**Notice: Undefined index: pesquisar**

Segue códigos

```
<?php
 try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXX', 'root', 'XXX');
 } catch (PDOException  $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
 }
?>



 <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>
  <input name="cxnome" type="text" id="cxnome" value="" size="30">
  </label>
  <label></label>

  <label>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" name="pesquisar" value="Pesquisar">
  </label>
&nbsp;
<label>
<input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Limpar">
</label>
</form>




<?php

$nome=$_POST['cxnome'];
$pesquisa=$_POST['pesquisar'];

if(isset($pesquisa)&&!empty($nome))
{
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE :letra");
$stmt->bindValue(':letra', '%'.$nome.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$resultados = $stmt->rowCount();

if($resultados>=1){

echo "Resultado(s) encontrado(s): ".$resultados."<br /><br />";
while($reg = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
echo $reg->nome." - ";
echo $reg->email."<br />";
}
}
else
{
echo "Não existe usuario cadastrado";
}
}
else{
echo "Preencha o campo de pesquisa";
}
?>
```

Comment: _já tentei mas está complicado_ - para facilitar você poderia explicar melhor como já tentou, o que tentou, o que não deu certo...

Comment: Só está difícil fazer com que a pesquisa fique na mesma página pois assim que a pesquisa é feita é redirecionado para outra página

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro está aqui

```
<?php
$nome=$_POST['cxnome'];
$pesquisa=$_POST['pesquisar'];
...
?>
```

Quando você faz isso, você está atribuindo o valor de `$_POST['cxnome']` a uma variável, sendo que `$_POST['cxnome']` ainda não está definido, já que na primeira vez que você entra na página você ainda não efetuou o formulário.

Uma solução para esse seu problema é colocar uma condição de existência para que `$nome` receba `$_POST['cxnome']` apenas se este estiver definido:

```
if (isset($_POST['cxnome'])){
  $nome=$_POST['cxnome'];
  $pesquisa=$_POST['pesquisar'];
}
```

O mesmo vale para `$_POST['pesquisar']`

Comment: Cara eu estava com a cabeça tão quente que acabo deixando até simples erros passar e mesmo eu olhando várias vezes, não acho o erro KKKK
Muito obrigado!!!
Valeu demais!!